# Problem filling the board with a set of numbers

Tags: problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

I have a exercise that don't have the solution, accordingly i want to know if my solution was correct.

Exercise:

> Can you fill a 3X3 board with the numbers $\{ -1, 0, 1\}$ such that the sum of rows, columns and diagonals are different?

My solution was:

With that set of 3 numbers i can get these sums $\{ -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$ here are $7$ different sums, but a $3X3$ board have $3$ rows, $3$ columns and $2$ diagonals that is $8$ sums and therefore at least one will be repeated. Is my solution correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz and thanks Rob Pratt for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments. Your approach and result are correct.